# Do optical mice actually take pictures from their surface?

Tags: mouse

I tested several optical mice and wondered whether they really **Take Pictures** of their surface or only of the **reflecttion of the LED or LASER** that is emitted from the mouse?

1. If mice take a picture every millisecond or less then where are the pictures saved?
2. Can we access the pictures from the computer?
3. If the pictures are processed by a DSP(digital signal processor) then why is it that on some surfaces optical mice don't detect the movement of the mouse but laser mice do detect it?  ([source](http://www.howstuffworks.com/question631.htm))
4. I tested that on some surfaces like wood that has a wooden pattern optical mice don't work, however they work on completely black mouse pads?

Answer (score 0):

Suggest google and [How Stuff Works](http://computer.howstuffworks.com/mouse.htm).

Optical mice don't take pictures that are saved anywhere. They use two images to compare them to each other and then throw away the old one to make room for the next image.

> The technology underlying the modern optical computer mouse is known
>   as digital image correlation, a technology pioneered by the defense
>   industry for tracking military targets. Optical mice use image sensors
>   to image naturally occurring texture in materials such as wood, cloth,
>   mouse pads and Formica. These surfaces, when lit at a grazing angle by
>   a light emitting diode, cast distinct shadows that resemble a hilly
>   terrain lit at sunset. Images of these surfaces are captured in
>   continuous succession and compared with each other to determine how
>   far the mouse has moved.

Some surfaces reflect that light better than others.

Comment: the optical mouse actually uses a tiny camera to take 1,500 pictures every second

Comment: updated to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Optical mice don't save any pictures to your computer, so there is no way for you to access them, unless you were to somehow rewire the mouse's hardware. Even if you could access the pictures, they would be very low resolution because the mouse has a very low resolution video camera.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_mouse for more info.